# How can I write to stdout using FlatFileItemWriter in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, iostream, java-io, spring-batch

I have the following writer configured in my beans definition file of a spring batch project :

```
<bean id="writer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:/path/to/somefile"/>
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="MyCustomLineAggregator"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now, instead of writing to /path/to/somefile, I want the output to go to the stdout, reason being that I want to launch this job through the command-line launcher and pipe the output to another unix program.

I tried by setting the resource property to "file:/dev/stdout", but then I get the exception :
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Unable to create file: [/dev/stdout]

I tried to see if there was an out of the box resource that could handle this, but I'm a bit clueless on which one could do the job...

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : Below is the solution I came up with, following your advise :

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.LineAggregator;

public class StdoutWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T> {

LineAggregator<T> lineAggregator;

public void setLineAggregator(LineAggregator<T> lineAggregator) {
    this.lineAggregator = lineAggregator;
}

@Override
public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
    for (T item : items) {
        System.out.println(lineAggregator.aggregate(item));
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Here you can find the implementation for the same. 
 https://github.com/akkida746/SpringBatch.git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is anything out of the box that does what you are looking for. It is simple enough to create your own `ItemWriter` that does a simple `System.out.println()`. You can then use the [`CompositeItemWriter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html) to tie the two together if you still want the file.

Alternately, you can throw on a custom [`ItemWriterListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html) and do the printing there.

Comment: Indeed writing my own itemwriter was the easiest solution. Thanks and sorry for not thinking of it upfront :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's another hack you can use to write to stdout. Essentially, you can specify `/dev/stdout` as the output file resource. Be sure to set `shouldDeleteIfExists` to `false` and `appendAllowed` to `true` within the writer or you'll get runtime errors.