# Spring batch, how do I write simple strings into a file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm new to spring batch and so far I've studied how to take a list of Objects as input from csv,xml,json files or DBs and write down those same Object in external files or DBs.
However I just realized that I don't know how to output simple strings, for example I've made this simple Processor:

```
public class ProductProcessorObjToStr implements ItemProcessor<Product,String> {
    @Override
    public String process(Product product) throws Exception {
        return product.getProductName();
    }
}
```

So that I get a simple list of names but I have no idea how to create the correct item writer.
I've studied theese kinds of writers where I map the various Object fields:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter flatFileItemWriter(@Value("#{jobParameters['outputFile']}") FileSystemResource outputFile){
        FlatFileItemWriter writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<Product>();
        writer.setResource(outputFile);
        writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator(){
            {
                setDelimiter("|");
                setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor(){
                    {
                        setNames(new String[] 
                        {"productID","productName","productDesc","price","unit"});
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        writer.setHeaderCallback(new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {
            @Override
            public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
                writer.write("productID,productName,ProductDesc,price,unit");
            }
        });
        writer.setFooterCallback(new FlatFileFooterCallback() {
            @Override
            public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
                //scrivo il footer
                writer.write("****** File created at  " + new SimpleDateFormat().format(new 
                Date()) + " ******");
            }
        });
        return writer;
    }
```

Which writer do I use for strings and how do I create it?
Thank you in advance for your suggestions !
Have a nice day.

Comment: Just use the same but for a single column.

Comment: Maybe this worth a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338223/how-can-i-write-to-stdout-using-flatfileitemwriter-in-spring-batch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I write to stdout using FlatFileItemWriter in spring batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338223/how-can-i-write-to-stdout-using-flatfileitemwriter-in-spring-batch)